# C++/C# Header of bgr32 bitmap

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, bmp

To my understanding, the srgb32 is only a 24-bit color depth image with 8 bits of padding at the end.
ie, a blue pixel in little endian:

```
byte1_b = 255
byte2_g = 00
byte3_r = 00
byte4 = 00 //padding
```

What has got me confused is how should my headers look like to indicate this padded encoding. If I am not mistaken, simply setting the color depth to 32 won't work because that enables alpha channels. How should I encode this?

Edit. This is a project that is done both in C++ and C#. I am using WritableBitmap class to render a fractal image. But the actual image is drawn through the backend api in C++ using P/Invoke. Hence the title is C#/C++ to emphasize that I am working in these two environments.

Comment: C and C# are *extremely* different languages, and C doesn't have any access to .net frameworks like WPF. So please [edit] your question to remove the irrelevant C language mentions. Or if you're programming in C then C# and .net are irrelevant. Also please take some time to refresh [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Comment: I am handling the actual coding in C++, C# is there to indicate where bgr32 is coming from

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got it. Changed to C++

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150576/what-is-the-fourth-channel-in-bgr32-pixelformat) helps.

Comment: Use [`PixelFormats.Bgr32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pixelformats.bgr32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_PixelFormats_Bgr32). It is a 32-bit BGR format with an unused fourth byte.

Comment: The bit map has an ASCII header inside the binary file.  So if you look at a mage file with srgb32 with NotePad you will see the ascii string.  So just make the class header look like the string in NotePad.

Comment: @jdweng Could you give me instructions on how to create a bitmap file of srgb32 and save it to a file. I need this precise information to recreate it on c++ side. Others have gotten confused with my description.

Comment: Maybe the title of your question is totally misleading. What else than the pixel format is the "pixel structure of bitmap" supposed to mean? The encoding of color channels in a raw pixel value does also not depend on the programming language that you are using.

Comment: @Clemens its bgr32 pixel structure. Which is unique from a normal 24 bit pixel structure or a normal 32 bit pixel structure with alpha channels. But I admit its misleading, what I really needed are the headers.

Comment: Look at line 186 and 213 : https://github.com/cdepillabout/termonad/blob/master/src/Termonad/Config/Colour.hs

Comment: @jdweng I'm sorry, I don't know Haskell. I will try to generate a bitmap file and read its headers.

Comment: The code show a string to use for the header.  If you have a graphic card that supports the mode usually there are tools supplied with the card that can generate for image or there are sample images that come with the graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question albeit raising more questions. This Microsoft [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd183376(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) describes that the high byte is ignored by default. I tested it out and the image seems unchanged regardless of the padded byte.